# Connection noise in rodio when starting a playback

Tags: audio, rust

I am using [rodio](https://crates.io/crates/rodio) for the reproduction of some file, with this code:

```
extern crate rodio;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::time::Duration;
//..
let endpoint = rodio::get_default_endpoint().unwrap();

let file = std::fs::File::open("./sound/beep2.wav").unwrap();
let mut beep1 = rodio::play_once(&endpoint, BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();

beep1.set_volume(0.1);
```

When starting playback, I hear a noise like a connection noise at the beginning. This sample file ([beep2.wav](https://github.com/tomaka/rodio/blob/master/examples/beep2.wav)) plays without noise in a normal player program.

I have created alternative code but the noise stays the same:

```
//test duracion inicio

use rodio::Sink;
use rodio::Source;

let mut sink = Sink::new(&endpoint);
let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();

sink.append(source);
sink.set_volume(0.01);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this noise at the beginning of the reproduction?

Comment: If I had to take a guess... I would say that it is likely that the soundifle that you are playing back has a nonzero sample value for its first sample. This is causing your speakers to "instantaneously" jump from 0 to whatever that value is. As to why it does no do this when played back in other ways: I would imagine that whatever you are using to play back the file is applying a very small crossfade to the start of playback to avoid such pops and clicks in your playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `set_volume(0.1)` which is causing your waveform to be discontinuous. This results in a theoretically instantaneous movement in your speaker cones which will sound like a pop or click. If you remove the `set_volume` line it should fix your problem.